# Checking text from an external page

Tags: jquery

I have a text file with email addresses and urls that can be opened by a specific email address.
For example:

```
john.smith@operator.com http://google.com
ivan.dewilde@operator.com http://vrt.be
```

(this text file can be constantly updated with email addresses and urls by the administrator of the page)

When ivan dewilde enters his email address in an input field and presses "send" he is automatically sent to the page "http://vrt.be".
The link may only be valid for one month.
How can I solve this with jquery?

This is the html:

```
<input type="text" id="txtUsername">
<button> Submit </button>
```

After "submit" the user is sent to the page from the second column of the text file.

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: $("button").click(function() {
        var username = $('#txtUsername').val();
        location.href = "url from the second column";
})      I would like to have the command to find the url that matches the email address

Comment: There is no command for this, you have to get it and parse it yourself.